# Export complex tables from a node.js app hosted in the cloud to excel files

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js, export-to-excel

we are trying to implement an export feature to our web app.

Our app generates large tables of data, and we want the User to be able to simply export its table into newly created xlsx files:

- Format must be kept (so no export in CSV)
- Subtotals and totals included in the tables must be written down in Excel as a Sum formula ;

What would you use to perform that task ? 
Do you think the Office Javascript for Excel API could be used to create, read and write into Excel files from a Node.js app hosted in the cloud ?
If not, could you please detail why not ? 
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Eddyvaub for your question, I am sorry office.js currently do not provide API to export tables to an external workbook, I would suggest that you could submit your request in uservoice and upvote for this feature for Excel online at https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback?category_id=163563

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would also strongly recommend to use the sheetjs library which is great.